# Where is the source of getenv(...)?

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, fastcgi

I am studying the [FastCGI framework](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/5) for C++ but the getenv(...) function seems to be externally defined. Where can I find it's definition?

Comment: It's usually a built-in function, you'll find it in the source of your compiler -- if you have access to it

Comment: @Attila You can post that as answer. Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: What compiler and platform are you using?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews G++, I don't really need the source code, I just didn't know it was a built in function. (if it wasn't built in I'd be interested in it's source)

Comment: It's built into the standard library. In a typical case, it's not a terribly complex function -- for example, on most Unix-like systems, there's an external named `_envp` that contains a pointer to the environment strings, so basically all `getenv` does is walk through them to find the one you specified, then return the value associated with that name.

Comment: [Man Page: getenv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually a built-in function, you'll find it in the source of your compiler -- if you have access to it